# How to handle SIGTERM in OSX

Tags: c++, macos, unix

I have daemon app for OSX, I have signal handler for SIGTERM in my application.

I am trying to implement a check in application for SIGTERM,

something like this:

```
void stAgentService::SIGTERM_handler(const int sigid) {

    if (SIGTERM == sigid) {
         continue; //continue to run the app
    }
}
```

But I am not finding a way to continue to application after receiving SIGTERM.

My main intention is to handle SIGTERM initiated by "launchctl unload" command.

Comment: The meaning for `SIGTERM` is that your process should, you know, *terminate*. I'll bet anything that what really kills your process if you don't exit in a timely fashion after receiving `SIGTERM` is a `SIGKILL` which forcibly kills your process without letting you exit gracefully.

Comment: And to answer your question: The way to stop `SIGTERM` from killing your process is to *catch the signal*, that's all. The `continue` statement will do nothing.

Comment: the continue statement won't even compile

Comment: yes, I don't mean continue statement here, I want to write some code which will not terminate the app. If I don't do any thing inside stAgentService::SIGTERM_handler() still my application is getting killed. I tried to remove the SIGTERM handler all together still the behaviour is same.